# Jquery UI Autocomplete Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am facing issue in jquery ui autocomplete. I am trying to load a list with checkbox in using autocomplete. The _renderItem function is not getting called.

Refer below code.

```
$("#paragonId").autocomplete({
                               source: function( request, response ) {
                                       var params = new Hash();
                                       params.set('ajaxParam', '1');
                                       var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
                                       params.set('currentTime', currentTime);
                                       params.set('searchQuery', j$("#paragonId")[0].value);
                                       var actionUrl = '../DealReportCompanyCriteria/findParagonId.xhtml';
                                       var response = new Ajax.Request(actionUrl, {
                                       parameters: params,
                                       method:'post',
                                       asynchronous : false});

                                       var paragonIds = response.transport.responseText;
                                       return paragonIds;
                               },
                               delay:10,
                               minLength:4
                }).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                        alert('_renderItem');
                        return $("<li></li>")
                        .append( '<input type="checkbox" value='+item.label+' name='+item.label+'/>' + item.label)
                        .appendTo(ul);
                };
```

I tried 'ui-autocomplete' in data function but its giving exception and 'autocomplete' is working fine. Any idea why renderItem function is not getting called?

Comment: Is it alerting "IN Ajax Success" ?

Comment: No its not even alerting in ajax function

Comment: What that "j" is doing there ? in `j$("#mandateId")`

Comment: Can you post your HTML code ?

Comment: I tried using j$ and $ , J stands for jquery

Comment: Don't use both. You can use only "$" .

Comment: If I used only $ then its giving error undefined for that object. Any idea its happening due to jquery version ?

Comment: Show your HTML code. Without HTML it's bit hard to know whats happening in your code.

Comment: I have added my jsp code above

Comment: When I tried to used autocomplete as, j$("#mandateId").autocomplete(
    "../DealReportMandateCriteria/getMandateIdList.xhtml",{..}); It works and get data using url. But if I used as j$("#mandateId").autocomplete(
    {source:"../DealReportMandateCriteria/getMandateIdList.xhtml",...}); its not working. Even I tried to used source function still no luck, Is it due to jquery version ?

Comment: Right Click > Inspect > Console.  Check the error.